# PHP - example of function or class name with \x7f-xff char

Tags: php

PHP manual [says](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) that legal char set for class of function name is

```
[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]
```

And I m confused how to use `\x7f-\xff` as first char.

```
function 0x7ftest(){}
```

and

```
function \x7ftest(){}
```

raise execution errors.

Can someone make an example, plz?

Comment: `\x` means that it is hex-encoded. `\x7F` is the non-printable DEL character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\x` means that it is hex-encoded. `\x7F` is the non-printable DEL character. Many of the characters in the `[\x7f-\xff]` range are non-printable, or are modifiers that are used with other characters to modify what they look like.

You can use [this page](http://www.ascii-code.com/) to find the characters (in the *The extended ASCII codes* table, *HEX* column).

For example, you can use `\x8C` (the Œ character), like this:

```
function Œ() {
    return "Œ is a ligature of OE!";
}
echo Œ();
```

You should refrain from using these characters in your code because you cannot easily type them using most keyboards, and because most of them are non-printable (i.e. they do not appear on the screen as characters, or if they do they often appear as some "unknown" character: ?, � or □).

Comment: Tnx. I was confused with hex numbers part and rule specify char number that way.